# dynamic onClick not working

Tags: javascript

I know im doing something really really stupid here.Im getting the error document.getElementById() is null or not an object. Could some one please help me with this?

```
<body>
<div id="box1" style="width:100px;height:100px;background:#ccc;"></div>
<div id="box2" style="width:100px;height:100px;background:#ccc;"></div>
<div id="box3" style="width:100px;height:100px;background:#ccc;"></div>
<div id="box4" style="width:100px;height:100px;background:#ccc;"></div>
<div id="box5" style="width:100px;height:100px;background:#ccc;"></div>
<script>

for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
document.getElementById('box' + i).onclick = function() {alert('You clicked on box #' + i);};
}

</script>
</body>
```

Thank You

Comment: I'd suggest using a framework such as jQuery so the event bindings work across platforms.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Indexing Issue**

`i` is starting on `0`.  There is no box called `box0`.  Change loop to:

```
for (var i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
document.getElementById('box' + i).onclick = function() {alert('You clicked on box #' + i);};
}
```

**Scope Issue**

As pointed out by commentators, there is also a scope issue with the code.  Change it to:

```
for (var i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
  document.getElementById('box' + i).onclick = (function(index){
    return function() {
      alert('You clicked on box #' + index);
    };
  })(i);
}
```

Comment: I believe that should be `<=`.

Comment: +1 I wasn't even going to put that in an answer...  Was just going to leave a comment...

Comment: it should be `var i = 1; i <= 5; i++`

Comment: @ZDYN +1 to you too.  Good catch

Comment: @tom i knew i was doing something really silly,cheers mate.will mark this as the answer in 10mins

Comment: @TomGullen scope issue w/ the i within alert as well

Comment: YEAHHHH this answer is a rep factory!  I haven't caught one of these for a long time.

Comment: @kjy, I was under the assumption the loop body has the same scope as loop header?  Although I may be wrong...

Comment: there is a scope issue here, i was reading this article http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/scriptjunkie/ff696765

Comment: I tried it on jsFiddle and it did not work. Although I'm not the question poster, could you please have a look at: http://jsfiddle.net/7euMP/? i.e. all boxes return #6.

Answer (score 2):

I believe already got solution; anyway I just want to say that you have jQuery alternative too..

```
$(document).ready(function() {
     $("div[id*=box]").click(function() {
         alert('You clicked on box ' + $(this).attr('id'));
     });
 });
```